# How to store values of NSString into UITableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsstring

I have `UITextField`, `UITableView` and `UIButton`. I am storing the value of `UITextField` in `NSString` as shown below. When i press "done" `UIButton` i want to store the value of `NSString` in **first cell** of `UITableview`. When i enter a new string in `UITextField` and repeat the process that value should get store in 2nd cell and so on..

```
NSString *cellValues = textField.text;


- (UITableViewCell *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
                SampleTableview *cell;

}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  (Your title isn't a question, it's a way of saying "write my code for me".)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `NSMutableArray` property on your class (note that you should be complying with the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols):

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *listOfStrings;
@end
```

Make sure you set up your `UITableView` and your array correctly on the `viewDidLoad` method (if you dragged and dropped the `Table View Controller` object into the Storyboard, you don't have to do this):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.listOfStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

Setup the `tableView` delegate methods as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.listOfStrings count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listOfStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Then, when your press the `UIButton`, the method that gets called should add the `UITextField` text to the array and reload your `tableView`:

```
- (void)buttonPressed{
    [self.listOfStrings addObject:self.textField.text];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi oscar i am getting sigbart in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: @Coder Download here the example project: https://mega.co.nz/#!BZN2EL5R!F4_qOlaitBJzkgJgNZjqIncqwTVfHRfLCP9X7hjjiDU